# Get animation from custom attribute in constructor

Tags: android, animation, custom-attributes

I have a custom view, extending LinearLayout and im trying to add some custom attributes, like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <!-- other stuff -->
    <declare-styleable name="UIPlayer">
        <attr name="team" format="integer" />
        <attr name="playAnimation" format="reference" />
    </declare-styleable>
</resources>
```

My custom view is like this:

```
public class UIPlayer extends LinearLayout
{    
    // . . .

    public UIPlayer(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle)
    {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
        initAttrs(context, attrs);
    }

    public UIPlayer(Context context, AttributeSet attrs)
    {
        super(context, attrs);
        initAttrs(context, attrs);
    }

    public void initAttrs(Context context, AttributeSet attrs)
    {
        TypedArray taPlayer = context.obtainStyledAttributes(attrs, R.styleable.UIPlayer);
        int team = taPlayer.getInt(R.styleable.UIPlayer_team, -1); 
        player.setTeam(team);

        int animPlayId = taPlayer.getResourceId(R.styleable.UIPlayer_playAnimation, -1);
        try
        {    
            animPlay = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(context, animPlayId);
        }
        catch (NotFoundException e)
        {
            d("anim", "onPlay not found! " + animPlayId);
        }
        taPlayer.recycle();
    }
    // . . .
}
```

My layout file is like this:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:devn="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/devN.games.mygame"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:clipChildren="false"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:weightSum="3.0" >

    <devN.games.UIPlayer
        android:id="@+id/player"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:clipChildren="false"
        android:gravity="top"
        devn:playAnimation="@anim/play"
        devn:team="2" >
    </devN.games.UIPlayer>

    <!-- ... -->

</LinearLayout>
```

What im doing wrong and i cant retrive the animation from within the contstructor? (the "strange fact" is that the team attribute is working fine)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After a lot of studies in android source code, i tried the overload methode:

```
obtainStyledAttributes(AttributeSet set, int[] attrs, int defStyleAttr, int defStyleRes)
```

and it worked like a charm!! :)
So the correct code is:

```
TypedArray taPlayer = context.obtainStyledAttributes(attrs, R.styleable.UIPlayer, 0, 0);
```